# AdMob, Google Mobile Ad, switching from iAd, bannerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad

**iOS 9.3, Xcode 7.3, ARC enabled.**

I am migrating away from iAd, and I have some general questions regarding best design patterns and how to properly use the Google Mobile Ads framework for banner style ads.

1. How do you control presentation on ad load and load failure?

   My typical approach is to start with the banner view hidden, detect when the ad is loaded, then either animate the banner view in from the top or bottom, or fade in from a stand-in image.

   I noticed that `GADBannerView` class, does not have some of the more convenient properties of an iAd banner, such as `isLoaded`.

   a) Right now I take advantage of the two methods `- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView` and `- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error`, set an instance variable bool for the view controller when either method gets a message, then use that variable for any additional UI changes else where.  Is this a good design practice?

   b) "deleted", animation works.

   c) When the ad fails to load, what happens to the banner view?  I notice that its alpha property is still 1.0 and that it is not hidden.  In a production environment when an AdMob ad fails to load, is the banner clear?  Or does it have a generic stand-in image?  In other words, am I going to have to slide in an image to balance the view without the banner view there?
2. I've read from the basic AdMob tutorial that it doesn't really matter where the banner is, it can be in multiple view controllers, the framework will manage how these multiple banners will be filled.  Could someone confirm this behavior?  Say, I have two view controllers and I have two different banner views, I don't have to manage the ads?  All I have to do is provide the banner view real estate?
3. Generally speaking, if I used to have iAd for ads and also in-app. purchases through iTunes, then what is the modern day trend?  Am I supposed to have ads through AdMob and keep in-app. purchases as they are through Apple?  Is that what people are doing now?

Thanks in advance for your answers.  I know this maybe too general, but I really want some sort of a fundamental understanding where to head, before I submit anything to Apple.

--

Here is the code for animation I am using:

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
    bannerDidLoad = true;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        bannerView.alpha = 1.0;
        bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(bannerView.frame.origin.x, bannerView.frame.size.height, bannerView.frame.size.width, bannerView.frame.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        nil;

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really narrow your question down. It's kind of vague. Anyways, yes `GADBannerView`'s will be *clear* if they fail to receive an ad. Using the delegate methods to know what state the `GADBannerView` is in is the standard. Animating the `alpha` property should not be an issue. Not really sure what that last question is asking. You can use any ad network you'd like. If you're using in app purchases already just continue using them and remove the `GADBannerView` instead of the `ADBannerView`.

Comment: The last question is asking if the general trend is to have ads through AdMob and have in-app. purchases through Apple, AdMob has a way to integrate in-app. purchases too, but that's only for Android as far as I know.  It'd be nice to have one account, instead of two separate ones to track...  Is that what you are doing?  AdMob account to manage ads and still using iTunes connect for in-app. purchases, having two accounts?

Comment: My banner view is not animating, could you provide an example to slide the banner view in from off screen to on screen that works when the `- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView` gets called?

Comment: @serge-k Yes two accounts. You will have two accounts no matter what ad network you use seeing as iAd is being discontinued. Edit your question with the code you're using to animate your `GADBannerView`.

Comment: I think I was working late yesterday and something went wrong, it is working fine now on simulator and my iPhone 5s.  I deleted the part about it not working.  I put the code snippet in, does that look alright, its exactly what I was doing before for iAd.

Comment: So if you wanted to know the status of banner if it is loaded or not, you'd set some sort of instance variable?  Or send a message to a method containing some bool?  Is that what you'd do?

Comment: You could store a `BOOL` that you update in the delegate methods to determine if your banner has received an ad or not. As for the animation, I'd use the banner's `.height` rather than a static number, `50.0`. Also, I'd set the frame in relation to where I'd want the banner to appear rather than using `CGRectOffset`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. You have been very helpful, let this sit for a bit and see if anyone else chimes in; otherwise I'll mark to you.